# LUA export data from tcpdump

Tags: lua, tags, export

im new in Lua and Wireshark. So i have a tcpdump files and  need to export in xml or txt file all tcp packets- TCP Stream in a RAW format where source is 192.168.1.10. and the data wich i need is in 1st row between 23 and 28 possition in TCP stream in wireshark. Is it possible for automate?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Give an example of a file.

Comment: Where i can send you ?

Comment: Append an excerpt from your tcpdump file to your question so we can understand its structure.